# Automatic character encoding handling in Perl / DBI / DBD::ODBC

Tags: sql-server, perl, odbc, dbi

I'm using Perl with `DBI` / `DBD::ODBC` to retrieve data from an SQL Server database, and have some issues with character encoding.

The database has a default collation of `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, so data in varchar columns is encoded in Microsoft's version of Latin-1, AKA [`windows-1252`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

There doesn't seem to be a way to handle this transparently in DBI/DBD::ODBC.  I get data back still encoded as `windows-1252`, for instance, € “ ” are encoded as bytes 0x80, 0x93 and 0x94.  When I write those to an UTF-8 encoded XML file without decoding them first, they are written as Unicode characters 0x80, 0x93 and 0x94 instead of 0x20AC, 0x201C, 0x201D, which is obviously not correct.

My current workaround is to call `$val = Encode::decode('windows-1252', $val)` on every column after every `fetch`.  This works, but hardly seems like the proper way to do this.

Isn't there a way to tell `DBI` or `DBD::ODBC` to do this conversion for me?

I'm using ActivePerl (5.12.2 Build 1202), with `DBI` (1.616) and `DBD::ODBC` (1.29) provided by ActivePerl and updated with ppm; running on the same server that hosts the database (SQL Server 2008 R2).

My connection string is:

```
dbi:ODBC:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=localhost;Database=$DB_NAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This surprises me. What is the type of the column? What does  http://search.cpan.org/~mjevans/DBD-ODBC-1.29/ODBC.pm#odbc_has_unicode return for you. DBD::ODBC on Windows is usually built (by default) with -u and hence makes unicode ODBC calls and asks for SQL_WCHARs which should return UCS2 encoded data which is reencoded as UTF-8 for Perl.

Comment: @bohica: `$dbh->{odbc_has_unicode} == 1`.  The columns are all `varchar`, *not* `nvarchar`.

Comment: I maintain DBD::ODBC. Could you possibly reduce this to a simple script retrieving a row then run it with DBI_TRACE=15=x.log and post the log file somewhere (on windows probably set DBI_TRACE=15=x.log).

Comment: @bohica: will do.  In the meantime, even manually binding a column with type SQL_WVARCHAR or SQL_WCHAR doesn't make a difference.  Looks like the ODBC driver or DBD::ODBC doesn't know the data is in `windows-1252`-encoding...

Comment: As far as I am concerned it should not be in windows-1252 if asked for as SQL_WCHAR.

Comment: @bohica: trace log in http://mscha.org/tmp/x.log .  Code is basically: `my $sth = $dbh->prepare(...); $sth->execute(); $sth->bind_columns(\$col1, ..., \$colN); while ($sth->fetch()) { exit; }`

Comment: Oh, if it helps, the first row (the one that is fetched), contains an € (0x80) in the 2nd column (Title).

Comment: you mean the 3rd column (Title)? i.e., 'eBookbon: . 10' contains a euro?

Comment: could you repeat with column 3 (title) or whichever column is supposed to contain a euro bound as SQL_WCHAR and repost the log? BTW, DBD::ODBC does NOT know the data is windows-1252 - there is no way to find out. I'm very surprised I've not seen this before. You can always RT it at http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=DBD-ODBC but I'm not sure I'm going to add decoding of windows 1252 all over the place - will think about it though.

Comment: Yes, indeed the 3rd column.  (Gotta have some more coffee if I can't count to three anymore...)

Comment: Okay, I added `$sth->bind_col(3, undef, SQL_WCHAR);`, and in spite of what I said earlier (I must have tried column 2 then...), it works, I get a properly decoded €.  I tried both before and after `$sth->bind_columns(...)`, both appear to work, but strangely, only in the latter case the trace log shows "€" instead of ".".  Trace logs in http://mscha.org/tmp/x2.log and http://mscha.org/tmp/x3.log for both attempts.  (x2 is before, x3 is after `bind_columns`.)

Comment: Sorry, another correction.  (I forgot to remove my manual decoding.)
Only if I add `$sth->bind_col(3, undef, SQL_WCHAR);` *after* `$sth->bind_columns(...)`, it works.  This matches with what the trace logs say.

Comment: Setting `odbc_default_bind_type` or `odbc_force_bind_type` to `SQL_WCHAR` on either database or statement handle does not help, by the way.

Comment: Neither of those settings for bound columns - they are for bound parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DBD::ODBC (and ODBC API) does not know the character set of the underlying column so DBD::ODBC cannot do anything with 8 bit data returned, it can only return it as it is and you need to know what it is and decode it. If you bind the columns as SQL_WCHAR/SQL_WVARCHAR the driver/sql_server should translate the characters to UCS2 and DBD::ODBC should see the columns as SQL_WCHAR/SQL_WVARCHAR. When DBD::ODBC is built in unicode mode SQL_WCHAR columns are treat as UCS2 and decoded and re-encoded in UTF-8 and Perl should see them as unicode characters.

You need to set SQL_WCHAR as the bind type after bind_columns as bind types are not sticky like parameter types.

If you want to continue reading your varchar data which windows 1252 as bytes then currently you have no choice but to decode them. I'm not in a rush to add something to DBD::ODBC to do this for you since this is the first time anyone has mentioned this to me. You might want to look at DBI callbacks as decoding the returned data might be more easily done in those (say the fetch method).

You might also want to investigate the "Perform Translation for character data" setting in newer SQL Server ODBC Drivers although I have little experience with it myself.

Comment: Thanks.  Binding the `varchar` columns as `SQL_WCHAR` or `SQL_WVARCHAR` is probably my best option for now.  Certainly better than decoding manually...

Comment: FYI, I changed DBD::ODBC unicode build in 1.30_1 so all char data is bound as SQL_WCHARs and it should avoid the issue you reported at http://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=67994